# Where does the below function get parameters from?

Tags: javascript, function

Function `getFunc` is not passed a parameter, why is this code working ?

```
function getFunc() {
    const a = 7;

    return b => {
        console.log(a+b);
    } }

const f = getFunc();

f(5); //12
```

Comment: The function *returned* from calling `getFunc` does indeed take a parameter.

Comment: You are returning a function from `getFunc`

Comment: Ref. https://eloquentjavascript.net/

Comment: Passing a link to a book is not very helpful on its own. The bit on closures is covered in chapter five. https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called closure.

In JavaScript, the code inside functions has access to the variables defined inside this function and to variables defined in all parent functions.
If you refer to a variable in the child function that's defined in the parent function and then you return child function JavaScript will preserve variables from the parent functions and they will be available in returned functions.

In your example, you're returning child function

```
b => {
    console.log(a+b);
}
```

from `getFunc` function so child function still has access to the variable `a` defined in parent function. When you execute `f(5)` child function executes `7 + 5` expression and you get `12` in the console.

Comment: Thanks very much, I now understand.

Answer (score 2):

getFunc returns the anonymous function

```
b =>{
  console.log(a+b);
}
```

so when you make a call to getFunc you're really calling `console.log(7+parameter)`

Comment: I understand what you mean, but what you wrote is incorrect. Console.log is never called when calling getFunc.

Comment: Thanks very much, I now understand. Plus Closure
const f = function (b) {console.log(a+b)}

Answer (score 1):

```
function getFunc() {
const a = 7;

return function(b) { //it is more clear syntax
    console.log(a+b);
} }

const f = getFunc(); // here we have a function wich get 'b' parameter

f(5); //here we call this function and pass 5 as a 'b' parameter
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I now understand.

Comment: Glad to help you. Mark than my answer as an "Answer". That other users can find this answer as well